# Running ssh command on server from Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ssh, server, centos

I have a Jenkins stage as:

```
stage("Deploy on Server") {
   steps {
      script {
          sh 'sshpass -p "password" ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" username@server "cd ../../to/app/path; sh redeploy.sh && exit;"'
      }
   }
}
```

and some scripts on my server (centos):

**redeploy.sh:**

```
declare -i result=0
...
sh restart.sh
result+=$?
echo "Step 6: result = " $result

# 7. if restart fail, restart /versions/*.jar "sh restart-previous.sh"
if [ $result != "0" ]
  then
    sh restart-previous.sh
    result+=$?
fi

echo "Deploy done. Final result: " $result
```

**restart.sh**

```
nohup java -Xms8g -Xmx8g -jar app-name-1.0-allinone.jar &
```

Because I execute the redeploy.sh script from the Jenkins, the problem is that it will cling on Jenkins console and will log all application events there, instead to create a nohup file in the patch where my app is deployed.

In some examples I found that it is recommended to use nohup directly in ssh command, but I can't do this because I need to execute a script (with all the steps, nohup can't doing that) and not directly a command.

`exit` cmd will be ignored because the previous command will never be closed.

thanks

Comment: Are you using a declarative pipeline? What is the concern in `restart.sh` printing data in jenkins console output? I would suggest you let it print in `Console Output` but find a way to mask the parameters which contain sensitive data so that in jenkins console output it appears as `******`. I also recommend you to use shell syntax like this `sh ''' echo "This is my shell script" '''` as outlined here: Ref: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/running-multiple-steps/

Comment: I found a way ... is needed to force from the cmd to log into a logfile, as "nohup java -Xms8g name.jar </dev/null>> logfile.log 2>&1 &". this is in centos server. But, the problem is when I try to kill an existing process, because in jenkins is returning error 255, even if the command are executed successfully: def statusCode = sh returnStatus: true, script 'sshpass -p password username@server sh redeploy.sh'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution. One problem was in `restart.sh`, because is needed to force from cmd to specify the log file. So, `nohup` is ignored/unused, and the command become:

```
java -Xms8g -Xmx8g -jar app-name-1.0-allinone.jar </dev/null>> logfile.log 2>&1 &
```

Another problem was with killing the previous jar process. Be very carrefour, because using project name as path in jenkins script, this will create a new process for your user and will be accidentally killed when you will want to stop your application:

```
def statusCode = sh returnStatus: true, script: 'sshpass -p "password" ssh -o "StrictHostKeyChecking=no" username@server "cd ../../to/app/path/app-folder; sh redeploy.sh;"'

if (statusCode != 0) {
   currentBuild.result = 'FAILURE'
   echo "FAILURE"
}
```

**stop.sh**

```
if pgrep -u username -f app-name
  then 
    pkill -u username -f app-name
fi
# (app-name is a string, some words from the running cmd to open tha application)
```

Because `app-folder` from Jenkins script and `app-name` from `stop.sh` are equals (or even app-folder contains app-name value), when you'll try to kill `app-name process`, accidentally you'll kill the ssh connection and Jenkins will get `255 status code`, but the `redeploy.sh` script from server will be done successfully because it will be executed independently.

The solution is so simple, but hard to be discovered. You should be sure that you give an explicit name for your search  command which will find **only and only** the process id of your application.

Finally, `stop.sh` must be as:

```
if pgrep -u username -f my-app-v1.0.jar
  then 
    pkill -u username -f my-app-v1.0.jar
fi
```